# Comparing a number with an array of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to write a code wherein I have to compare a number with all the elements of an array. The number can be equal to only one element of an array or not equal to any element. I can compare the number with each element of the array using if statement inside a for loop. Problem is when I want to write "the number is not equal to any of the element of the array".The code shown below will execute the else statement 99 or 100 times, but I need that to be executed only once, after number is compared with all X[i] and not found equal.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(number == X[i])
    {
        cout << "number is equal to one of the numbers in array" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "number is not equal to any number in the array" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: put a `break` inside the `if` (after the printing line). Or use `std::find`

Comment: Here's a hint: use a `bool` to track the condition you need to inside the for loop. After the loop, check the value of the `bool`

Comment: @UnholySheep: OP needs to iterate over the entire array.

Comment: As discussed in previous answers, I'm unsure if he wants once, only one, more than once conditions. I've tried to provide an answer that can be adjusted to meet any of these conditions - a simple counter - but clarification would be ideal here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good grief!  Just run a counter then at the end of the loop check the counter value...1 means only one match....0 means no matches....more than 1 means that the array contents seem to violate the conditions asserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should be correct: when it finds an element of the array which is equal to the number you're looking for, it breaks the loop converting the `bool` variable into true. So, if it is false (`if(!check)`) the number is not in the array.

```
bool check = false;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(number == X[i])
    {
        cout<<"number is equal to one of the numbers in array"<<endl;
        check = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!check)
    cout<<"number is not equal to any number in the array"<<endl;
```

Comment: This code is unfortunately not correct. OP stated "The number can be equal to only one element of an array". If we break after matching just one, we exclude the possibility that another number might equal the target, and thus the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment... In my code when it finds an element which is equal to the number, it breaks because "The number can be equal to only one element of an array", not 2 or 3, and so it's useless to go on with the loop.

Comment: That is another interpretation of OPs statement that I did not consider. It can be interpreted to mean "There won't be duplicates in the array" or "there may be duplicates in the array, and if there are, then do not match". Please make an edit to your post so I can retract my downvote.

Comment: This code worked exactly the way I wanted. The number can be equal to at maximum one number or none. Only if the number is equal to none it executes the last if statement, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an algorithm provided by the STL. The [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find) algorithm is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: `std::find` will exit as soon as it finds a single match. OP needs to ensure that "only one element of an array" will match. "Only one" being the key phrase here. `std::find` will not indicate duplicates.

Comment: As he wrote "The number can be equal to only one element of an array" its not exactly clear if he want to know if a value exists only once or if his code ensures that a value exists at most once. Nevertheless, if the first one is true `std::count` , of course, would fit better.

Comment: That is an interpretation I did not consider. Unfortunately my downvote cannot be removed unless you edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are comparing **"number"** with every number in the array **"X"**, and every time the 2 numbers are **not** equal you are printing that statement.

What you want is something more like this:

```
bool foundNumber = false;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

    if(number==X[i]){

        cout<<"number is equal to one of the numbers in array"<<endl;
        foundNumber = true;
        break; //The "break" command just exits out of the loop and if you already know it's equal, you can just exit the loop

    }
}

//Now that we are out of the loop, we check the "foundNumber" variable
if(foundNumber==false){

    //If "foundNumber" is false, then we can print out that we did not find the number
    cout<<"number is not equal to any number in the array"<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may provide the answer you are looking for, using a counter to find out if it exists multiple times or not. NB - I haven't run this code! As far as I am aware, it is more extensible given the *slightly* ambiguous question, and should meet your needs of whether you need to find a value that appears once, *only* once, or more than once.

```
unsigned int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(number == X[i])
    {
         count++;
    }
}

if (count == 1) //Edit with == x, or > or < symbols to change frequency requirements
    cout << "Number exists " << count << " time(s) in array"<<endl;
else
    cout << "Number does not exist only once in array" << endl;
```

Comment: I liked the logic you are using. It's simple and solves my problem.